# Visa with a criminal record

Tags: air-travel, schengen, schengen-visas, estonia

I got my Schengen visa for Estonia on April 5th from the German Embassy. My travel plan was 1st to 16th of May 2018.

I bought my ticket from Finnair on 1st of May. I had to take a flight on that day. But I couldn’t take the flight. I don't understand why. They told me Finland immigration didn’t allow me and my family to take the flight for Estonia. Finland is only transit for me. They couldn’t let me. I had a visa  and hotel bookings.

Another day, I changed my plans. I bought tickets from Thai Airways. I booked a hotel in Munich and Estonia. They told me I could not take the flight to Munich. The reason was hotel bookings. I asked many times the reason, they told me your hotel bookings.

After that I cancelled my trip to Estonia because of this reason. After some days, I got an email from the German Embassy. They asked me please bring your passport, we will review your visa situation then I replied. I am not in Bangladesh. What should I do about the email? They didn’t answer.

Another day I requested one of my friends to go to the German embassy in Dhaka. Officers in the embassy told that person the visa was cancelled and that I needed to bring the passports. My friend told them I'm not there, and would not come back to Bangladesh. They didn’t take care or listen to him.

After some days a police officer called me. The German Embassy had a complaint to Interpol about me. Interpol told them I was using a fake visa to go to Germany. The German embassy gave that visa on April 5, 2018. How is it possible to be fake? How can I remove that complaint about me from Interpol? What should I do? What is the solution?

Comment: I can't quite understand your question here. Please try to be more concise.

Comment: How did you get your visa? Did you get it yourself or did you use some kind of agency or service to help you get a visa? Is it possible that the people you got the visa from were really scammers?

Comment: I got it myself .

Comment: If you're not  in Bangladesh, where are you? How did the police contact you? And what does this have anything to do with a criminal record?

Comment: @Bekmezci Which German embassy did you apply to and where did you go to for your biometric appointment?

Comment: Already the beginning of your story sounds odd. The *German* embassy would (at least should) not have issued you a visa for a visit to *Estonia*, as they are not the competent authority for issuing such a visa. Assuming that you have a single-entry visa: Trying to use such a visa issued by German authorities for a trip to Estonia is indeed a valid reason for refusing entry (and for the airline to refuse transport).

Comment: "The German Embassy had a complaint to Interpol about me. Interpol told them I was using a fake visa to go to Germany." This is confusing. The first sentence makes it sound like the complaint originated with Germany, while the second makes it sound like it originated with Interpol. "They asked me please bring your passport" Bring it where? The German Embassy in Dhaka? "After some days a police officer called me." A police officer from what jurisdiction? Germany? Dhaka? Interpol? Somewhere else?

Comment: @Bekmezci, your question has been closed as unclear. dda hat edited it yesterday, but there was no clarification from you. It does not become clear where you are resident, where you applied for a visa, and so on.

Comment: @Bekmezci, without clarification it is impossible to help.